# perl run background job and force job to finish?

Tags: perl, ipc, kill-process

I've got a Perl script that starts a background job to print some
logging information into a file, executes something, and then
finishes.

I would like to end the background process when the script is done,
but as far as I know, if I use a double fork as below, then `waitpid($pid,0)`
will wait for the background process to finish, instead of killing it, 
and `kill(9,$pid)` won't get rid of the background process.

Example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

# Do a first general top
my $ret = `top -b -n 1 > logfile`;

# Do a background $USER top every minute
my $cmd = "top -b -d 60 -n 300 -u $ENV{USER} >> logfile";
my $pid;
unless ($pid = fork) {
  unless (fork) {       #second_fork
    exec "$cmd";
    die "exec failed!";
  }                     #second_fork
  exit 0;
}

# Script does something else for 1-2 hours
# [...]
# We are finished now, let's finish the logging

# waitpid($pid,0) would wait until top command is finished
force_background_job_to_finish($pid) if (background_job_still_running($pid));

# Add final top to the end
$ret = `top -b -n 1 >> logfile`;

1;
```

Any ideas how to `force_background_job_to_finish`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$SIG{CHLD}="IGNORE";
my $cmd = "top -b -d 60 -n 300 -u $ENV{USER} >> logfile";
if (my $logger_pid=fork) {
    # parent
    do_something_for_1to2_hours();
    kill 15, $logger_pid;
} else {
    # child (logger)
    exec($cmd);
}
```

Comment: If there is nothing before the `kill` command, it does indeed kill it, but if I add a dummy `sleep 5;` instead of     `do_something_for_1to2_hours();`, I can still see the logger process running after the kill command.

Comment: My mistake, try with `kill 15` (SIGTERM) instead of `kill 1` (SIGHUP).  Answer edited.

Comment: I changed it to kill 15, but I can still see the `top` command running.

Comment: If you added `$SIG{CHLD}="IGNORE"` then the `top` process should die and be reaped immediately after being killed. Run this one-liner: `perl -le '$SIG{CHLD}="IGNORE"; if($pid=fork) { sleep 1; kill 15, $pid; system "ps $pid"; } else { exec "top -b -d 1 -n 300 -u $ENV{USER}" }'`  - you should see the output of `top` once, and then only the header row from the `ps $pid` command, correct?

Comment: Your one-liner is now for me, I think I may have missed something when I copy+pasted it from my script.

Answer (score 2):

Usually double fork is used so that you don't have to worry about reaping child processes.  Since you want to control the child process, you can just do a single fork, which will give you the process id which you can then use to kill your child process using kill.

Comment: so if I get rid of the lines labelled #second_fork, how do I kill the background process? `kill(9,$pid)` doesn't kill it.