# ipc perl killing background job requires killing two pids

Tags: perl, ipc, kill-process

This question is related to a previous question:
[perl run background job and force job to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19029855/719016)

I thought I had a script working that would successfully kill my background job by doing `kill 15, $logger_pid`, but it turns out the command creates two jobs. See details below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
# Do a background $USER top every minute
my $cmd = "top -b -d 1 -n 300 -u $ENV{USER} >> logfile";
$SIG{CHLD}="IGNORE"; my $logger_pid;
unless ($logger_pid=fork) { exec($cmd); }

# This actually creates two jobs with consecutive PIDs
# $USER  5609  0.0  0.0  63820  1072 pts/9    S    09:42   0:00 sh -c top -b -d 1 -n 300 -u $USER >> logfile
# $USER  5610  0.6  0.0  10860  1216 pts/9    S    09:42   0:00 top -b -d 1 -n 300 -u $USER

# Do something for a while
foreach my $count (1..5) { print "$count\n"; sleep 1; }
# I thought this first kill command was enough
kill 15, $logger_pid;
# This line is needed to kill the child job
kill 15, ($logger_pid+1);

1;
```

Can someone enlighten me on why I need a second `kill 15, ($logger-pid+1)` to actually kill the background job? Is there any way to do this with one single `kill` statement?

Comment: They will often be consecutive process IDs, but you should not rely on that.

Comment: @mob, yes, that's my fear: I would rather have a way of killing the background process in one go.

Comment: Try using a negative signal `kill -15, $logger_pid` (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=298613)

Comment: I tried `kill -15, $logger_pid` but it doesn't kill any of the two processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system using `sh -c ...` to execute an external command with shell metacharacters (in your case, the `>>` for output redirection, and for that matter any spaces in the command string) is documented in `exec` and `system`. To avoid using `sh -c` and to create a single process, you can use the `LIST` form of `exec`:

```
my @cmd = ('top','-b','-d','1','-n','300','-u',$ENV{USER});
exec(@cmd);
```

The output redirection makes this a little tricky, but you can accomplish it by closing and reopening `STDOUT` after the `fork` and before the `exec`:

```
my @cmd = ...
close STDOUT;
open STDOUT, '>>', 'logfile';
exec @cmd;
```

When doing output redirection, the important thing is to set up file descriptor 1 correctly, not necessarily `STDOUT`. This, for example, will fail to do output redirection like you want it to.

```
my @cmd = ...;
close STDOUT;       # close file descriptor 1
open FOO, '>/tmp/asdf';        # probably uses file descriptor 1
open STDOUT, '>>', 'logfile';  # probably uses file descriptor != 1
exec(@cmd);                    # probably writes output to FOO\/tmp/asdf
```

---

**Alternate solution using process groups:** @Chris suggests in a comment that you send a negative value to the `kill` function in order to kill an entire process group. Normally the process you create with `fork` has the same process group as its parent, but this will work if you set up the child process to use a new process group:

```
unless ($logger_pid = fork) {
    use POSIX;
    POSIX::setpgid($$,$$);   # set child process to be in its own process group
    exec($cmd);
}

...

kill -15, $logger_pid;       # kill the process group with id $logger_pid
```

Comment: I used the `POSIX::setpgid($$,$$)` method together with the `kill -15, $logger_id`, and it now works.